# Need a term for a graph-theoretic/metric concept

Tags: terminology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and define $\rho$ to be the largest distance of any $x\in X$ to its nearest neighbor.

Formally,
$$ \rho = \sup_{x \in X}~ d(x, X \setminus \{x\}). $$

Does this quantity have a name? It's zero in continuous spaces and is only interesting in discrete ones.

Comment: If I name it, I might call it “largest isolation.”

Comment: I was thinking "isolation distance".

Answer (score 2):

Sloan calls this the "covering radius" when distributing points on a sphere.  http://www2.research.att.com/~njas/coverings/

Comment: Covering radius is slightly different because it is defined in terms of a metric space X and its (usually finite) subset S, whereas in this question there is only one metric space.